# Digital Signature is not valid

Tags: certificates, cryptography, email, certificate-authority, smime

I recently received a digital signed email from a friend and the certificate is issued by COMODO RSA Client Authentication and Secure Email. My problem is the thunderbird detect it as a "Not Valid Signature"

Here's the pic:

[image]

I double checked the CA Authorities on thunderbird and it is already trusted, now I can't reply an encrypted and digitally signed email because of this problem. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you check that the CA Authorities certificate in you store and the CA presented here have the same fingerprint ?

Comment: Was the certificate still valid when it was used to sign?